# Treeview inside grid and proportional size

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working in a WPF app that uses a Grid, an inside the grid a couple of TreeViews:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Header"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="Tree1"" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="SecondHeader" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="Tree2" Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>
```

With this setup, the headers will have the size proportional to the Grid's size.

The problem happens when I have a tree smaller, and I have a white space between both trees, and if the first tree is empty, It will also occupy the half of the grid.

If I change the code to this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Header"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="Tree1"" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="SecondHeader" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="Tree2" Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>
```

I get a very similar result to what I want, but in this case the scrollbars of the trees won't show up, because the trees will occupy all the area they need and it will overflow my grid.

If I enclose this second solution inside a scrollviewer, I would get a common scroll for the whole grid:

```
<ScrollViewer><Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Header"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="Tree1"" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="SecondHeader" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="Tree2" Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid></ScrollViewer>
```

The problem of this solution is: If the first tree is long enough, the user won't see de second tree unless he scrolls down, and is a requirement that both trees are visible always.

Resuming I need a setup with the following features:

- Display both treeViews inside the grid
- Those treeviews must have their own scroll
- If one of the treeviews has no elements, the shouldn't be a gap.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a solution for 1 and 2 features that you need:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="131"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="171"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TreeView x:Name="Tree1" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Header">
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 1"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 2"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 3"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 4"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 5"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 6"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 7"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 8"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 9"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 10"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 11"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 12"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
        <TreeView x:Name="Tree2"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100">
        <TreeViewItem Header="SecondHeader">
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 1"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 2"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 3"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 4"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 5"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 6"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 7"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 8"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 9"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 10"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 11"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="item 12"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

The TreeView controller has a Scrollable property, but to enable this property, TreeView or its container needs to have a height.

With this, you can see both TreeViews in the same Grid and each controller have own ScrollBar.